# Errors in building Android project in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am trying to convert an ios project to Android in cocos2d-x.
I performed create-android-project.sh and build_native.sh and it seemed fine.
I imported the created android project into eclipse and found some errors.

These lines(class name) have red underline which is compile error.

this.setEGLContextClientVersion(2); in Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java
this.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompletedListener()); in Cocos2dxSound.java
this.mSoundPool.autoPause(); in Cocos2dxSound.java
SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener in Cocos2dxSound.java

What kind of error is this and how can I fix it?
Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you should have at least 2 projects.. your project.. and libcocos2dx project (in cocos2dx/platform/android/java)
In your main project click on properties, then android and add libcocos2dx as dependency.
Let me know if you have any other issue.. with exactly what compilation errors you have.

Comment: Thank u for your comments. I clicked properties and then clicked Android. But I can't find how to add libcocos2dx as dependency.

Comment: You can edit 'project.properties' directly and add this:   android.library.reference.1=some-path/cocos2dx/platform/android/java